# call ajaxStart and ajaxStop selectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a webpage where ajax calls trigger an overlay using jQuery like so:

```
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() { $("body").addClass("loading");    },
    ajaxStop: function() { $("body").removeClass("loading"); }    
});
```

This is fine for me, however there are a couple of ajax calls in the page which are background jobs and I do not want the `loading` message to be shown for those ajax call.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. You need to set the global to false in the `$.ajax()` method only where you don't want to apply the `.ajaxStart()/.ajaxStop()` events to be fired:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'',
  global:false, //<----add this
  success:fn
})
```

#### Note:

*You can use it in `$.ajax()` only.*

---

From the docs:

> **global** (default: true)
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> Whether to trigger global Ajax event handlers for this request. The default is true. Set to false to prevent the global handlers like **ajaxStart** or **ajaxStop** from being triggered. This can be used to control various Ajax Events.

Comment: thanks this helps...my functions are $.post, need to check if it will work there.

Comment: @UndefinedVariable you can see i have suggested you to use `$.ajax()`. Although i have never tried to use `global` in `$.post() etc.` shorthand ajax methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `flag` variable defined in *window* scope, set it to `false` when you do not want to `ajaxStart / ajaxEnd` effect. Otherwise it should be `true`

```
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() { if(ajaxFlag){ $("body").addClass("loading"); ajaxFlag=true;    },
    ajaxStop: function() { if(ajaxFlag) $("body").removeClass("loading"); }    
});
```

Comment: if i set it to false, then next place would I need to set it to true again? if I do then it will be a hassle..

Comment: You can set that true after add class in the condition